# .Batch renaming multiple files

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-rename

Hello guys I have this code in .batch:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=C:\Users\leandro.batista\Desktop\reni"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.pdf" ') DO (
 SET "csvname=%%~na"
 IF NOT "!csvname:*_=!"=="!csvname!" (
  CALL :finddate

    REN *.pdf !csvname!.pdf 
    PAUSE
)
)


GOTO :EOF
:finddate
IF /i "%csvname:~-13%"=="" SET "csvname=%csvname:~0,-13%" 
IF "%csvname:*_=%"=="%csvname%" SET "csvname=%csvname:~0,13%"&GOTO :EOF  
SET "csvname=%csvname:*_=%"
GOTO finddate
```

So yea, now I'll explain, I have the :finddate that extracts a part of the filename and then I use it in the for Loop to rename the files.
What I am doing is renaming multiple files in the same folder but I am having the problem that it isn't renaming multiple files, it just renames me 1 file and then leaves the others and says that a file with the same name already exists, so I think that my loop isn't working as I want it to work.

The file name example is this:

```
AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD_01_M73N_(REC9ago2017) BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA 1008.pdf
```

I would need some help with this problem.

Comment: The Ren command should rename the current file with `REN "%%a" "!csvname!.pdf"` The command `IF /i "%csvname:~-13%"=="" SET "csvname=%csvname:~0,-13%"` is nonsense: if the last 13 chars are empty (would mean that csvname is empty) shorten csvname to remove last 13 chars. [Edit] your question to contain some example names.

Comment: It's edited, you can now see the name of the file

Comment: And what do you expect, what is the desired result?

Comment: It's done, the problem is solved, I used the "%%a"

Comment: Oh, and by the way LotPings, forgot to answer you, the IF command wasn't nonsense, it was to extract the (REC9ago2017) from the name and it works like a gem.

Comment: The command ***is*** nonsense. The if can only be true in case csvname is completely empty (the /i is also superfluous when comparing with an empty string which has no case)  When csvname **is** empty why strip chars from it?

Comment: Is there a reason why your initial `Dir` command doesn't look for only `.pdf` files containing an underscore, `For %%A In ("%sourcedir%\*_*.pdf") Do …`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem thanks to @LotPings.

I just did this in the REN line:

```
REN "%%a" "!csvname!.pdf"
```